# Error in calculating Timezone of Brasilia

Tags: javascript

```
function(startDate, lastDate){


var midDate = newDate(startDate.getFullYear(),startDate.getMonth(),Math.ceil((lastDate.getDate() + startDate.getDate()) / 2));

var startDateOffset = startDate.getTimezoneOffset();
var lastDateOffset = lastDate.getTimezoneOffset();
var midDateOffset = midDate.getTimezoneOffset();

var finalDate = new Date();
if(startDateOffset == midDateOffset){

  if((lastDate.getDate() - midDate.getDate()) > 1){
    alert("loop");
  finalDate = this.getDaylightChangeDate(midDate, lastDate); 
  }
 }
```

I am getting start date as 20 oct , end date as 22nd and mid date again as 20th oct . This is happening only for the location Brasilia , also startDateOffset & midDateOffset is 180 as output.. which is throwing the code in infinite loop as mid date is equal to start date always. Please suggest some other method in javascript to calculate the mid date

Comment: You don't have any loop there.

Comment: loop is just an alert, it comes when offset time becomes equal for mid and start date. Actually the problem is with DST in brasilia , please check http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=45  . As mid date when i get 21st mid night the offset time make it 20-oct-2012 23:00:00 and this is where the code goes into loop.

Comment: Please rename the alert then if it is not a real loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The mid date between 2012-10-20T00:00 and 2012-10-21T23:00 *is* 2012-10-20T23:30. Of course your code can't expect the dates to differ if the input dates are no more than 2 days apart. What would even happen if you passed in the same date as start and end?

If those dates were recorded in different time zones, you always should use UTC to calculate differences.

Comment: After the whole execution I get the start date as 20-oct-2012 23:00:00 UTC-0300 and end date as 22-oct-2012 23:00:00 UTC-300 and the mid date same as start date.                             finalDate = this.getDaylightChangeDate(midDate, lastDate);   this passes the above dates every time. And i get the same output. Also used date(Date.UTC(year,month,date)) method but again getting the mid date and start date same

Comment: You can see the difference in the above two dates is 2 days, but still the mid date is wrong

Comment: Have you tried `midDate = new Date( (startDate+endDate)/2 )`?